# How to load the original image from flickr?

Tags: java, android, flickr

I'm trying to change the link _m to _o but I am still unable to get the original flickr image. Is there any possible ways? I am able to provide the full code if needed. I took away the farm as it is unable to contain.

```
 entry.setUrl("https://"".staticflickr.com/"+serverId+"/"+ photoId +"_"+secret+"_m.jpg");
```

Comment: have u checked if the original size is only available if the owner allows it in their settings?

Comment: Yes, owner allows it in their setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should have link to this foto with /sizes/o/

for example look here

https://www.flickr.com/photos/llnl/9403051123/sizes/o/

it gives orginal foto.

Comment: May i know how should i code it in android java? Because I am quite clueless on how should i code it.

Comment: Post more of ur code. becasue i dont know what it is in ur 1 post

Comment: Is it possible if i send you my entire code through your email? Because I unable to paste all the coding over here.